# How to handle naturally imbalanced dataset

Tags: machine-learning, data-science

I am working on a binary classification model. The population of this two-class naturally maintains 15-85% ratio. After implementing Random Forest or Xgboost algorithms the precision and recall for 15% class is very poor but not for 85% class. I used oversampling and undersampling methods.  But it only increased the recall value. What is the best approach to handle the situation?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Undersampling** should mostly not be prefered because it causes a huge amount of data loss. At the end, we are giving so much effort to collect data and it basically does not make sense when we throw them away.

**Oversampling** usually works better but the problem is that the synthesized samples might be noisy and might not perfectly reflect the real world situations. So, it also creates some deficiencies.

Usually, the best to introduce class weights in your loss function. The weights should be then anti-proportional to the number of samples you have for that particular class. So, I suggest you to use a custom loss function with class weights. It is integrated in most of the frameworks